# Mysql table content automatically change in a particular time?

Tags: php, mysql

I have 10 date columns with my mysql table. Dates are storing in the format 'D, d M, Y'. I want a code that will change the particular date column that containing todays date, to something like 'yy-mm-dd' format, at midnight 12:00. Is this possible?

Comment: Is this to sanatize your data? You could then just run an update statement against the whole database.

Comment: How its possible. Can u give me the code.?

Answer (score 0):

Your first columns are VARCHAR? So you need 10 new columns with DATE type.

Have a look at [STR_TO_DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date). You can use that in an update statement like this:

```
UPDATE yourtable SET newdate1=STR_TO_DATE(olddate1, yourdateformat), newdate2 ...
```

`yourdateformat` is the format of your old date described in [this format](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format).

Comment: OK... where i want to give this code? While inserting or calling?

Comment: You only have to use it once to clear your complete database.